# When is it soon enough to use new Java features?

Tags: java, compatibility

I'm developing an application that I plan to publicly release, or at least share with a  group of people. The problem that I am facing as a developer is compatibility. On my machine, I am using the new Java 8, but I am afraid to use its new features, and in fact, I'm even afraid to use the new features in Java 7, like `try-with-resources`, in fear that the users will not have an up-to-date Java version, and consequently, will not be able to use my application. For example, my school's computers still use Java 6.

First off, am I correct in thinking that? Or can code compiled with a newer JDK run on a machine with an older JRE? If I am correct, is there an established "rule" or standard for compatibility? Something like, "Make sure your code is compatible with a JRE that is two versions old!" Or is it purely a matter of the developer's judgement of when new features should be utilized for a released work? And just for emphasis, I am talking about just running the program. The user will never have to compile it.

I know this is a bit open ended, but this is the best place that I could think of to ask.
Thanks.

Comment: Given the security updates present in any release of the JRE, it's in users' best interests to use the latest JRE, so from my perspective, I'd say use what's available!

Comment: Oracle maintains a "[Support Roadmap](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html)" that lets developers know when they will stop updating each version of Java. For example, they stopped updating Java 5 in October 2009 and Java 6 stopped receiving updates in February 2013. You can use that information to decide whether it makes sense to keep supporting Java 6.

Comment: That depends entirely on you. I'd be focusing on Java 7 feature no (I love you multi catch). Frankly, there's no point in using a JDK if you're noting going to take advantage of its features, you might as well stick with the one your targeting. In most cases (the school is obviously not something you can control), but if you need a particular feature or bug fix, then your users will need to upgrade.  This is of course, entirely contextual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can always specify the version of Java that you want to support by compiling it with the `-version` flag.  This means, since you're using Java 8, you could always force your code to compile down to a lower version (that is, Java 6).

To your point about older Java versions - yes, you'll likely run into that.  A lot of people don't update their Java version for one reason or another.  But, this is where you have to make a decision:  do you choose to support their version, or do you choose to support another version?  This particular part is open-ended, but depending on what you ultimately want to use  in your code (diamond operator, try-with-resources (which is actually *very* nice), NIO), then you'd want to use the version of Java that works well with you and with what you want to support.